# Perform action when navigating away from a page

Tags: jsp, navigation

I have a UI page which is defined in tiles-def.xml and contains many other pages. Basically, it is a cluster of many small `JSP` pages. Hence, in my page, there are different ways of navigating away from current page in UI. So, is there any way I can perform an action when I navigate away from the current location irrespective of where I'm going - including logging out and closing the browser or the browser tab?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the [`windows.onbeforeunload`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/WindowEventHandlers.onbeforeunload) function which gets triggered before the window *unloads*.

In your case, it will look something like

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
    // call logout codes
}
```

Or

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
    window.close() // close the browser or tab
}
```

Comment: but will this approach work for FF, Chrome and IE-8 & later versions?

Comment: The [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/WindowEventHandlers.onbeforeunload#Browser_compatibility) I included provides information on browser compatibility. Short answer is 'yes'.